# Is it possible to book a non-standard Russia-Poland border crossing?

Tags: borders, russia

Is there any bureau or agency that can allow crossing the border from Russia to Poland on a given time outside of the standard checkpoints? My idea is sending a formal request, paying some fee and receiving some kind of notarized approval for a given time and place. The on-site guards would probably need to be informed about this too.

But is it even possible to arrange it like this? I mean after getting a proper visa and everything and entering Russia through an official checkpoint.

The goal here is to go cross the border at the Vistula Spit as a tourist (no business travel) on foot or on a bicycle.

Comment: Related, though focusing on other border crossings in Kaliningrad Oblast:  [Can you walk from Lithuania to Poland through Russia (Kaliningrad Oblast)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157320/can-you-walk-from-lithuania-to-poland-through-russia-kaliningrad-oblast/157347)

Comment: Given the sheer obduracy of Russian immigration, I would be astonished if this was possible without *very* well placed contacts, but do let us know if you pull it off!

Comment: FWIW, I am aware of similar arrangements in connection with special events at other locations along the Russia-Schengen border. E.g. at the NOR-FIN-RUS border tripoint, there have been occasional new year events taking advantage of the three time zones meeting there and allowing the participants to celebrate the transition into a new year three times, one hour apart in each of the three countries. Here, special permits have been issued to the participants to allow crossing the border outside the designated checkpoints.

Comment: You can't cross at Vistula Spit, there is no checkpoint, only a fence and signs and a watch tower.